# Permissions error when creating an A record

Tags: terraform, debian-buster, bind9

I have a Bind9 name server working. When I tried automating the creation of A records using Terraform there is a permissions error.

In journal -xe:

```
Jul 05 19:28:10 Bind9DNS named[2051]: client @0x7f34300e4170 X.X.X.X#64718/key terraformkey: updating zone 'example.com/IN': adding an RR at 'www.example.com' A X.X.X.X
Jul 05 19:28:10 Bind9DNS named[2051]: /etc/bind/zones/forward.example.com.jnl: create: permission denied
Jul 05 19:28:10 Bind9DNS named[2051]: client @0x7f34300e4170 X.X.X.X#64718/key terraformkey: updating zone 'example.com/IN': error: journal open failed: unexpected error
Jul 05 19:28:10 Bind9DNS named[2051]: client @0x7f34300e4170 X.X.X.X#64719: update 'example.com/IN' denied
```

Comment: I'd verify the user has permission, and check the terraform syntax

Comment: @neaumusic The terraform syntax is good because it fails on "terraform apply". Also, I am having a hard time trying to figure out the user that is making the changes. Do you know the user is "client" or something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for days, this reddit post helped:
[Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Proxmox/comments/13rikm3/bind9_terraformdynamic_update/?onboarding_redirect=%2Fr%2FProxmox%2Fcomments%2F13rikm3%2Fbind9_terraformdynamic_update%2F)

These are the commands to fix the permission errors:

```
echo /etc/bind/zones/** rw, > /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named
chown bind:bind -R /etc/bind
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/named
```